# Node.js proxy service for DocumentDB

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb

We want to work with Azure DocumentDB from AngularJS SPA. I understand that it's best to have node.js proxy service as a middle tier in between them. I'm a .NET developer and having trouble creating it. Can you point me to any code samples for such proxy?

Comment: This is not really a great question for Stack Overflow, but in general, read up on how to create a REST API in .NET and how to access DocumentDB from .NET. You will expose your own API which is probably a subset of the functionality offered by DocumentDB only covering the parts you need for your application.

Comment: Larry, thank you for your comment. I've created .NET service but I thought converting JSON to POCOs and then back to JSON doesn't make much sense. And node.js service would require less maintenance in the future as it will just pass JSON through. Am I wrong here?

Comment: Ohh, I misunderstood. I thought you wanted to create it in .NET. Here is an example that I've put up on GitHub: https://github.com/lmaccherone/temporalize-api. The drawbacks to that example for your case are 1) It has a lot more functionality than you want including temporal analytics which add a lot of complexity; 2) It's based upon an older DocumentDB SDK which doesn't support partitioned collections. That said, you might be better off with an actual proxy service. I've never use the Azure API Management/Gateway, but it looks like it might do the trick for you without any coding.

Answer (score 2):

Azure provides the DocumentDB SDK for C#, you can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-get-started/ for how to handle DocumentDB operations in C#.

And then, you can leverage the [API Apps in .Net](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-dotnet-get-started/) implementing with the DocumentDB SDK for C#, to expose the APIs for your Angularjs SPA.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use APIM (Azure API Management/Gateway) as a proxy or middle tier in between your SPA and DocDB. This way you don't have to code your middle tier but use APIM which is a PaaS service and also provides rich set of functionalities.